# Generate a set of sorted random numbers from a specific range

Tags: python, random, generator

I'd like to generate a set of x unique random numbers and sort them in Python. For example:
range(1000, 10000)
x = 100

I've figured out to import random and use the random.randrange method, then loop to get 100 random numbers and in the end sort them.

However, I don't know how to get unique numbers (such that they do not repeat) - should I validate each and every loop? Or is there any other easier way how to do it? And how should I sort them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`random.sample`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample)

```
numbers = random.sample(xrange(1000, 10000), 100)  # or `range` in Python 3
```

The sorting part is easy - use the [`list.sort`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) method.

```
numbers.sort()
```

By default this will sort it from smallest number to largest, but it takes an optional `key` argument which determines what to sort it on.

There is also a [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) function which doesn't modify a list in-place, but rather returns a sorted list.

```
numbers_sorted = sorted(numbers)
```

This also has an optional `key` argument.

Comment: Thanks @Volatility! Never thought it was THAT easy.
One more thing - is there a way how to export these numbers to csv or let's say xml format?

Answer (score 0):

[`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools) implements the [`random_combinations`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.random_combination)  itertools recipe, which returns `r` sorted random numbers, if given a sorted input.

```
import more_itertools as mit

mit.random_combination(range(1000, 10000), r=100)
# (1016, 1112, 1233, 1367, 1446, 1460, 1518, 1807, 1832, 1956, ...)
```

This is unlike `random.sample`, which returns an unsorted result.

---

**Details**

Looking at the recipe, we can see why this order is established.

From [itertools recipes](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.random_combination):

```
def random_combination(iterable, r):
    """Return a random *r* length subsequence of the elements in *iterable*.
        >>> random_combination(range(5), 3)  # doctest:+SKIP
        (2, 3, 4)
    This equivalent to taking a random selection from
    ``itertools.combinations(iterable, r)``.
    """
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    indices = sorted(sample(range(n), r))
    return tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
```

`range()` is inherently sorted and becomes the `pool` from which random elements are selected.  Although the indices are randomly selected, they are later sorted. Since the `pool` and `indices` are both sorted, the results are also sorted.

In summary, this does the same as @Volatility's answer, except the sorting is handled for you.

*Cavaet*: [`random_combinations`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.random_combination) requires the length of the iterable to exceed the value of `r`, otherwise an error is raised.