# How to generate pairs of random numbers that first number is smaller than second one

Tags: python, arrays, random

I want to generate pairs of random numbers that the first number is smaller than the second one like `[[3 8] [2 5] [8 9] [8 10] [5 9] [3 7]]`. I tried with the following code but since all the values generated randomly some of the first elements are greater than the second ones and some of them are equal.

```
a=random.randint(1, 10)
b = np.random.randint(1,10,(a,2))
print(b)
```

Comment: just swap the position if 1st number is greater

Comment: @Jan This approach won't work if 1st number is 1 or min

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate a set of sorted random numbers from a specific range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14748910/generate-a-set-of-sorted-random-numbers-from-a-specific-range)

Comment: You haven't said anything at all about the numbers other than that the second one is bigger. So for example you could choose the first one between 1 and 10, and the second one between 11 and 20. More detail is needed in this question.

Answer (score 4):

Seems most solution so far don't take into account that two independently generated random numbers could be equal.  (Which OP states he doesn't want).

I think `sample` is better.

```
from random import sample
sorted(sample(range(1,10),2))
```

This guarantees 2 unique numbers in increasing order.

Comment: it is not working when I am changing the size to :sorted(sample(range(1,10),(a.2))), which a is a random number.

Comment: why a.2?  why not a?

Answer (score 2):

One approach world be to sort the random numbers after generation

```
sorted([randint(1, 10), randint(1, 10)])  # [3, 7], [4, 6], [1, 10]
```

Comment: This doesn't guarantee that the numbers are not equal, which is a requirement according to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since the number are just random, you can simply add the following to you code:

Same as you did:

```
a = random.randint(1, 10)    
b = np.random.randint(1, 10, (a, 2))
```

Then:

```
b = [sorted(pair) for pair in b]
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate two ints and sort:

```
sorted(np.random.randint(0,100,2))
[28, 94]
```